# Using Ajax Form and Pagination - losing search parameters on next page selection

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Ok - someone must have done this before me.

I have a an Ajax form (Ajax form helper) that has a search box and some checkboxes to filter stuff.  The search results are rendered beneath by way of a partial view.  See below:

[image]

Here is the code:

**Search.cshtml**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchStuff", "FooController", new AjaxOptions
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    OnFailure = "searchFailed",
    LoadingElementId = "progress",
    UpdateTargetId = "search-results",
}))
{
    <div>
        <div class="search-filter">
            <span class="searchFilter">          
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkAll" checked />
                All
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkJournal" />
                Journal
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkBook" />
                Book
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkBookChapter" />
                Book Chapter
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkReport" />
                Report
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkWebsite" />
                Website
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkPersComm" />
                Personal Comm
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkConference" />
                Conference
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkMap" />
                Map
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkThesis" />
                Thesis 
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="searchbox">
            <input type="search" name="q" autocomplete="off"/>
            <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Search" /> 
        </div> 
    </div>
}

<div id="search-results" class="search-results">

</div>
```

**Problem with Pagination**

I have now started to try and get a bit clever and I have included an Ajax Pager to have pagination returned in the first set of search results.

[image]

Problem is, I have to retain all values in the ajax search form when the user selects the next page to render, but when I debug back at the SearchStuff method in FooController - it doesn't know anything about the search parameters.  Can anyone suggest what I should do to send the search parameters on?

```
<div class="pager">
    @Html.Raw(
        Ajax.Pager(new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "search-results",
            OnBegin = "beginPaging",
            OnSuccess = "successPaging",
            OnFailure = "failurePaging"
        },
                      Model.PageSize,
                      Model.PageNumber,
                      Model.TotalItemCount,


                      new { controller = "FooController", action = "SearchStuff"})
    )
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpMethod="Get" in new AjaxOptions. and change your controller with Request[] to get the search parameters.

Refer

[Filter is getting lost in WebGrid + Paging + Sorting + Filtering in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051794/filter-is-getting-lost-in-webgrid-paging-sorting-filtering-in-net-4-0)